# Swift doubleStored value type does not match pointer operand type

Tags: ios, swift, double

When I try to compile on iPhone 5S (64 bit) I get this error:

> Stored value type does not match pointer operand type! store i64 %387,
>   double* %indirect-temporary.span.latitudeDelta.value, align 8, !dbg
>   !471 doubleStored value type does not match pointer operand type!
>   store i192 %400, double*
>   %indirect-temporary.span.longitudeDelta.value, align 8, !dbg !471
>   doubleLLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted! Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

**EDIT**

The problem is in this func:

```
    func georeverseAddress(addess: String!) {
        var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addess,
            completionHandler:({ (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

                if error  != nil {
                    self.delegate.incomingError!(error)
                    return
                }

                if placemarks.count > 0 {
                    var cp : CLPlacemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                    var locationn = cp.location
                    var cord = locationn.coordinate
                    self.delegate.incomingUserLocation!(MKCoordinateRegionMake(cord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005))) // <---  Error Here
                    var pin = Pin(coordinate: cord)

                    var coordinate = "\(cord.latitude) \(cord.longitude)"
                    pin.title = addess
                    pin.subtitle = coordinate
                    self.delegate.incomingPin!(pin)
                }
        }))
    }
```

**FINAL EDIT**

if we avoid nested calls:

```
var cp : CLPlacemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
var reg = MKCoordinateRegionMake(cp.location.coordinate, span)
self.delegate.incomingUserLocation!(reg)
```

the error goes away, but now I get failed with exit code 254:

```
var reg = MKCoordinateRegionMake(cp.location.coordinate, span) // Error 254 here
```

it's strange, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: I suppose I should have said "show us **shortest** code necessary to reproduce your problem".

Comment: Sorry Kreiri, I can't figure out where is the problem

Comment: Well, comment out code until it stops happening. Or comment everything and uncomment until it starts happening.

Comment: The problem is in this line: self.delegate.incomingUserLocation!(MKCoordinateRegionMake(cord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005))) but I can't figure out where is the problem

Comment: look at `incomingUserLocation()` method code, then.

Comment: Split that line up so you aren't doing so many nested calls. That should narrow down which of the 3 things you're doing is causing the issue.

Comment: What is the type of self.delegate? What is the type of self.delegate.incomingUserLocation?

Comment: I would like to try your code but there is no self-contained code. What is the value of `placemarks`? What is the value of `cp.location.coordinate`? Create statements for these and `println()` them. `placemarks[0]` and `cp.location.coordinate`